# Searching two patterns for ground truth in python

Tags: python

I have to search for ground truth for a snapshot 'Image.webp' that comes in the form 'Image.jpg.yaml' or 'Image.jpeg.yaml'. It can have either  .jpg or .jpeg in the pattern. How do I check which one exists and make my snapshot_groundtruth accordingly.

```
snapshot_groundtruth = os.path.join(cfg.markup, dataset, image + '.jpg'+ '.yaml')
```

Further clarification: Actually actually both the image in .webp format and the ground truth are arguments used by a binary executable file. Image was converted to webp format from jpeg/jpg format. However, the ground truth is still 'jpeg/jpg + yaml' extension, so I need to search the right ground truth file for the '.webp' file.

Comment: I have no idea what "search for ground truth" means, or why you have images with .yaml suffixes or anything like that. Fortunately, all of that is irrelevant to the question. Which means you should have left it out, and you probably would have gotten an answer immediately, instead of scaring away 80% of the people who could have helped until you finally got lucky…

Answer (score 2):

The best way to check whether one file exists, and use the other if it doesn't, is to just try it:

```
try:
    snapshot_groundtruth = os.path.join(cfg.markup, dataset, image + '.jpg'+ '.yaml')
    snapshot = open(snapshot_groundtruth)
except FileNotFoundError:
    snapshot_groundtruth = os.path.join(cfg.markup, dataset, image + '.jpeg'+ '.yaml')
    snapshot = open(snapshot_groundtruth)
```

(Of course if *neither* one exists, that'll raise a second `FileNotFoundError`, but that's probably what you wanted, right?)

In Python, this idiom is called EAFP or EAFTP, for "Easier to Ask Forgiveness Than Permission". Don't pre-check whether something would work, just try it and see if it worked.

Besides being Pythonic, this also avoids race conditions that can lead to 1-in-a-million debugging nightmares and/or security holes. (What if the file existed when you checked it, but doesn't exist when you open it? Or vice-versa?)